# WP7 DateTimeFormat null creating IndexOutOfRangeException on dates

Tags: windows-phone-7, datetime, currentculture

I already posted a similar question but here I have a slightly different problem with it.
Situation in WP7.1 app:

CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("es");

If culture info is set to es (es-ES works fine but that cannot be the solution to hardcode that) than DateTimeFormat of current culture (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat) is null (throwing the IndexOutOfRangeException) causing simple DateTime.ToString() to fail with the same exception.

I need to make it work. I might be presuming something from above wrong, which I kind of hope that I do. Could someone either help me make it work, or point me to some msdn explaining it will not work ?

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe WP7.1 supports just 'es' for the culture code. See this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

Comment: actually figured it out with some help that day ... it does support just 'es', but 'es' does not contain any formatting according to this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx, so the solution was that it cannot be done and culture had to be changed to 'es-ES'